# Execute a dynamic action only if a page successfully submit?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a javascript function I would like to call when someone submits a form. However that form has database level validation. How can I make it so the function will only be called if the form successfully submits?

Or, to put it another way, how can I have a JavaScript function run only if there are no errors when submitting a page?

Answer (score 0):

Thus a successful submit reloads the complete page and forces a re-rendering of the page from server side the next moment you could execute a JavaScript function is on page load after that particular reload...

In APEX you could add a separate process to the submit processes which sets an Item to a value, e.g.

```
begin
  :p1_reload_success := 'Y';
end;
```

Then you could add a Dynamic Action which executes your JavaScript function on page load...The DA should then have a server side condition like this:

[image: DA condition]

But don't forget to reset the item value afterwards, e.g. to 'N', so the DA isn't executed again after the first execution...